# What happen when a lvalue assigned to a rvalue reference? No destruction of the temporary object?

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference, temporary, temp, destruction

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <cstring>

class Word{
    private:
        char* ptr = nullptr;
    public:
        Word(){
            cout << "default constructor" << endl;
        }
        Word(const char* sentence):ptr{new char [strlen(sentence)+1]}{
            strcpy(ptr, sentence);
            cout << "conversion constructor: " << ptr << endl;
        }
        Word(const Word& w):ptr{new char [strlen(w.ptr)+1]}{
            strcpy(ptr, w.ptr);
            cout << "copy constructor: "<< ptr << endl;
        }
        ~Word(){
            cout << "destructor: " << ptr << endl;
        }
};

int main(){
    Word a ("A stands for apple!");
    Word&& b = "B stands for Banana, rvalue ref";
    b = a;
}
```

My Eclipse result:

```
conversion constructor: A stands for apple!
conversion constructor: B stands for Banana, rvalue ref
destructor: A stands for apple!
destructor: A stands for apple!
```

My Extectation:

```
conversion constructor: A stands for apple!
conversion constructor: B stands for Banana, rvalue ref
destructor: B stands for Banana, rvalue ref
destructor: A stands for apple!
destructor: A stands for apple!
```

I am confused by this step.

```
b = a;
```

When a is assigned to b, it could suppose to first destruct the temporary object (with cstring of "B stands for Banana, rvalue ref") that b is holding, then assign the value of a to b. Why in the Eclipse's result, it does not perform the destruction of the temporary object?

Comment: Note that *all* the `char[]`s that you new in this class are leaked. Compilers are *permitted* (and in C++17 **required**) to omit some copies and moves, *explicitly* even if there would be side-effects, such as your `cout << "copy constructor: "<< ptr << endl;`

Answer (score 4):

Your expectation is wrong. There can't be more destructions than there are constructions.

> When a is assigned to b, it could suppose to first destruct the temporary object

No. `b` refers to the temporary object. Assigning to an object doesn't cause the object to be destroyed.

What happens is: The implicitly generated assignment operator of `Word` will assign all members. So, after the assignment the previous value of `b.ptr` is leaked and has the same value (points to same string) as `a.ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

`b = a;` is invoking the assignment operator, not the copy constructor.  If explicitly deleted, the code won't compile:

```
// trimmed...
Word(const Word& w):ptr{new char [strlen(w.ptr)+1]}{
    strcpy(ptr, w.ptr);
    cout << "copy constructor: "<< ptr << endl;
}
Word& operator = (const Word& w) = delete;
```

The compilation line:

```
$ g++ rvalue-ref.cpp -o rvalue-ref
rvalue-ref.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
rvalue-ref.cpp:45:9: error: use of deleted function ‘Word& Word::operator=(const Word&)’
     b = a;
         ^
rvalue-ref.cpp:20:15: note: declared here
         Word& operator = (const Word& w) = delete;
               ^~~~~~~~
```

The compiler will provide a default assignment operator, so the code in your question is leverage that.  To see what's happening, add copy-assignment and move-assignment operators.

```
Word& operator = (const Word& w) {
    auto temp = new char [strlen(w.ptr)+1];
    strcpy(temp, w.ptr);
    delete [] ptr;
    ptr = temp;
    cout << "assignment operator: " << ptr << endl;
    return *this;
}
Word& operator = (Word&& w) {
    std::swap(ptr, w.ptr);
    cout << "swap operator: " << ptr << endl;
    return *this;
}
```

With these in place, I get the expected output:

```
conversion constructor: A stands for apple!
conversion constructor: B stands for Banana, rvalue ref
assignment operator: A stands for apple!
destructor: A stands for apple!
destructor: A stands for apple!
```

As an aside, you're leaking memory.  Your destructor should look like this:

```
~Word(){
    cout << "destructor: " << ptr << endl;
    delete [] ptr;
}

$ valgrind ./rvalue-ref

==10736== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==10736== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==10736== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==10736== Command: ./rvalue-ref
==10736== 
conversion constructor: A stands for apple!
conversion constructor: B stands for Banana, rvalue ref
assignment operator: A stands for apple!
destructor: A stands for apple!
destructor: A stands for apple!
==10736== 
==10736== HEAP SUMMARY:
==10736==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10736==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 5 frees, 73,800 bytes allocated
==10736== 
==10736== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==10736== 
==10736== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==10736== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

You could also implement the assignment operator using the copy/swap idiom (below).  This will add an extra constructor/destructor output due to the temporary, but it's good practice overall.

```
Word& operator = (const Word& w) {
    Word temp(w);
    std::swap(ptr, temp.ptr);
    cout << "assignment operator: " << ptr << endl;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: This is somehow not really an answer and those operators are not really necessary especially since your implementation changes original behavior.

Comment: Using copy-and-swap to implement your copy assignment operator makes things a bit less clear.  It took me a little while to figure out where that extra copy-constructor call was coming from.

Comment: @VTT - The original code was getting the default assignment operator.  This version is changing the original behavior only enough to show what's actually happening.

Comment: Not really, this code introduces yet another `Word` object causing extra constructor and extra destructor invocation. I guess you should just do the same as stock operators + print message. I mean that `destructor: B stands for Banana, rvalue ref` is only printed because you've changed original behavior.

Comment: @VTT this is the answer. Rule of big 3; copy ctor, copy assign, dtor.

Comment: @Red.Wave this is the answer to *a different question*. OP wants to know why he is observing what he observes

Comment: @Red.Wave The primary point of user-defined constructors and operators in this example is to log call. However they should not change original behavior by introducing more temproraries.

Comment: swap, copy, assign is another good programming idiom. But since the OP has not provided a move ctor, a move assignment IMO is an overkill, unless a pairing move ctor is also provided(swapped after delegating to default).

Comment: @VTT did you even notice the memory leak due to not providing a user defined assignment?

Comment: @Red.Wave did you even notice that *every* `Word` leaks, due to the absence of any `delete`s to go with the `new`s?

Comment: @Red.Wave All those leaks are not really relevant here. For the sake of mcve OP could've thrown away all the memory management and just copy pointers backed by string literals.

Comment: @Caleth You got me. But it does not mean my previous comments were wrong. Good thing about the big 3 (big 5) with swap is that disposal of resources is concentrated in one place: dtor.

Comment: @Red.Wave I never disputed that. However, if the OP was asking what to do, I would suggest `using Word = std::string;` was the safest option

Comment: @VTT they are. You are proposing to define an immutable class; not practical. One can implement copy-on-write optimization based on your suggestion, but OP is not ready for that, yet.

Comment: @Caleth Obviously, this is a homework or a self motivated exercise, otherwise why is the clas name 'word'? I think OP is trying to avoid name collision.

Comment: @StephenNewell Caleth pointed out the missing 'delete' inside the dtor. Don't you want to complete your reply?

Comment: That's what I get for going on stackoverflow before driving to work :).  I'm at my desk now, so give me a few minutes to update the answer.

Comment: The problem with this answer (still) is that it does not answer the question. It is not "How to correct my code?", it is "What is happening here, and why the d'tor I am expecting is not called?" It's nice to provide a solid approach, but it's not nice to disregard the question. The problem are not forgotten operators, the problem is misunderstanding how the language works. You tell how to correct it, you don't explain why there is a problem in the 1st place.

Comment: @luk32 The problem here, was mistaking language features. If OP asks the wrong question, it doesn't mean he shouldn't get the answer he needs. I think the OP did not have enough expertise to ask the proper question; he sure can have it in a few month, unless indeed he gets frustrated due to confusion caused by complex hard to grasp answers. Forget about the wording. It is obvious that OP was not alert about assignment operator.

Comment: "*If OP asks the wrong question*" But they do not ask wrong question. The answer addresses wrong question. The question is clear. Understanding difference between "why it behaves like that" vs "what is a good practice" requires zero expertise. It's a different question. I get why for some reason you hold the right to disregard the literal meaning of the posed question to satisfy your view of OPs needs, but it seems like you are over-interpreting. Severing someone completely different answer without explaining what is wrong with their approach is condescending and halves the educational value.

Comment: Sorry, guys. Actually, I got the point. Yup, I am missing the defined assignment. And, there is a lot of problems in my code. There is a memory leak. Your comments are useful that teach me about the move semantics. Yes, I am still learning about the rvalue reference. That's why I am not so confident about it. But, I do know what you guys have mentioned. The first answer really solved my question. And, this answer further inspires me. So, really thx you guys.